# hotmail.com - Unrouteable address

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, exim

I'm using **Exim** on my mail server, and trying send email to *someuser@hotmail.com* address.
I got email from this address, and make "*replay*" then.

But - I have return from my **SMTP** with **Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender**:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

someuser@hotmail.com
     Unrouteable address

Return-path: <1th@domain.kiev.ua>
Received: from [37.***.***.56] (helo=[192.***.***.136])
    by mail.domain.org.ua with esmtpa (Exim 4.72)
    (envelope-from <1th@domain.kiev.ua>)
    id 1YAgu5-0005T4-Lp
    for someuser@hotmail.com; Mon, 12 Jan 2015 17:27:41 +0200
```

*someuser* - of course here is correct value.

`dig` returns all data for *hotmail.com*:

```
$ dig hotmail.com +short
157.56.172.28
65.55.77.28
157.55.152.112
65.55.85.12

$ dig hotmail.com +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> hotmail.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 17 bytes from 77.***.***.133#53(77.***.***.133) in 1 ms
```

*77.*.*.133* - my datacenter's **DNS**.

So - all seems correct, but...

P.S. Sent email from **Google** mail - and it was deliver normally.

**UPD**

```
$ telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25
Trying 65.54.188.94...
Connected to mx1.hotmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 BAY004-MC2F6.hotmail.com Sending unsolicited commercial or bulk e-mail to Microsoft's computer network is prohibited. Other restrictions are found at http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/anti-spam.mspx. Tue, 13 Jan 2015 08:29:47 -0800
```

Comment: Do `dig hotmail.com MX` on the server and try to connect with it using telnet or openssl s_client to see if it's exim or your network.

Comment: @sebix Thanks, but - it's works already. Seems was temporary problem with datacenter.

Comment: When it's working now, please answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you send your message via smarthost (mail.domain.org.ua) that is not properly configured and can't determine the way to the hotmail.com. Try to modify your outgoing router to send messages directly to the corresponding MX instead of smarthost.

Comment: `mail.domain.org.ua` is just MX for `domain.kiev.ua`, pointed to same server